# train(): argument “x” is missing, with no default

Tags: r

when i am trying the the following code I am getting an error: argument "x" is missing, with no default.

```
> library(caret)
    Loading required package: ggplot2

    Attaching package: ‘caret’

    The following object is masked from ‘package:survival’:

        cluster

    Warning messages:
    1: package ‘caret’ was built under R version 3.4.4 
    2: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.4.4 
    > library(kernlab)

    Attaching package: ‘kernlab’

    The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:

        alpha

    Warning message:
    package ‘kernlab’ was built under R version 3.4.4 
    > library(ROCR)
    Loading required package: gplots

    Attaching package: ‘gplots’

    The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

        lowess

    Warning messages:
    1: package ‘ROCR’ was built under R version 3.4.4 
    2: package ‘gplots’ was built under R version 3.4.4 
    > svm.data <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE) 
    >  str(svm.data)
    'data.frame':   2538 obs. of  5 variables:
     $ X        : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
     $ SessionID: int  13307 21076 27813 8398 23118 12256 28799 11457 7542 19261 ...
     $ Timestamp: Factor w/ 2532 levels "2014-04-01T03:02:33.088Z",..: 2064 905 1086 1027 2419 1327 2035 1206 481 1354 ...
     $ ItemID   : int  214684513 214718203 214716928 214826900 214838180 214717318 214821307 214537967 214835775 214706432 ...
     $ Price    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
    > dim(svm.data)
    [1] 2538    5
    > x <- subset(svm.data, select=-Price)
    > y <- svm.data$Price
    > table(svm.data$Price)

       0    1 
    1289 1249 
    > table(svm.data$Price) / length(svm.data$Price)

            0         1 
    0.5078802 0.4921198 
    > set.seed(123)
    > ctrl1 <- trainControl(method="cv", number = 2, summaryFunction=twoClassSummary, classProbs=TRUE)
    >    grid <- expand.grid(sigma = c(.01, .015, 0.2), C = c(0.75, 0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.25))
    >   svm.tune <- train(train.x=x, train.y=y, method = "svmRadial", metric="ROC", tuneGrid = grid, trControl=ctrl1) 
    Error in is.data.frame(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default.
```

how to solve this error?

Comment: You could have found this out via simply looking at the params before using it directly, isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving wrong argument in last line. Function `train` does not have any arguments like **train.x** and **train.y**. Instead do this-

```
svm.tune <- train(x, y, method = "svmRadial", metric="ROC", tuneGrid = grid, trControl=ctrl1)
```

It would solve this problem.